# XPath text() returns an extra blank value

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, import, google-query-language

I'm scraping [this site](https://www.helpmycash.com/hipotecas/hipotecas-interes-fijo/), specifically the content of the tables inside the `div` tags with `class` containing `'ranking-data'`. So for the first `td` that would be:
`//div[contains(@class, 'ranking-data')]//tr[th//text()[contains(., 'TIN')]]/td[1]/text()"`

This is working fine for all columns in all tables (with needed modifications) except for a cell in column 2 that contains an `i` tag: on Google Spreadsheets it adds an extra blank cell below the cell with the text itself. I've first tried to scrap it with:
`//div[contains(@class, 'ranking-data')]//tr[th//text()[contains(., 'TIN')]]/td[2]/text()`

Then I've tried something like `*[not(i[contains(@class,'info-circle')])]/text()` after the `td[2]`, and some other variants, but it doesn't work.

How can I avoid this `i` tag?

Comment: whats the url that causes your issue?

Comment: It's linked on "this site" :-)

Comment: so where is the issue? https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5yx1.png

Comment: Yeah, that `td` works; but not the next one: `//div[contains(@class, 'ranking-data')]//tr[th//text()[contains(., 'TIN')]]/td[2]/text()`. Sorry, I should have explained myself better and/or posted this one. Let me edit it.

Comment: The cell selected is the problem: https://i.imgur.com/iYQGyfv.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTXML(A1, "//div[contains(@class, 'ranking-data')]//tr[th//text()[contains(., 'TIN')]]/td[2]/text()"), "where Col1 <>' '", )
```

[image]

Comment: That was it. I was hitting my head against a wall with the XPath, and I forgot to try things outside the `IMPORTXML`. Well, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Answer given by @player0 is working for my case, and since it was the first answer I won't remove the "accepted" mark from it; but I'm stubborn and I've find an alternative with just XPath (which may be useful for other cases). It was as simple as adding an `[1]` at the end of my first query:

`//div[contains(@class, 'ranking-data')]//tr[th//text()[contains(., 'TIN')]]/td[2]/text()[1]`